# How to show a web page popup notification when pressing an inline button in a telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to show a popup spinner wheel similar to the one shown in this video at the 4 sec mark.
https://telegram.org/file/464001705/2/Hg-klQnZ_n4.4889245.mp4/d324511ffdab7b4668

I saw this video in the recent update blog from telegram
https://telegram.org/blog/payments-2-0-scheduled-voice-chats

Comment: I'm rather sure that this is just mock up for the blog and not actually doable.

Comment: Is this possible with an alert [notification](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery) and url to the webpage